# Not able to install seaborn libraries in python : Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, spyder

i am fairly new to this python programming language. i have installed anaconda, python and spyder (each separately) in my system. When working in spyder environment i am using the following command to install seaborn library

```
!pip install seaborn
```

and i am getting the following result

```
\users\16111317\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (0.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from seaborn) (1.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from seaborn) (1.19.3)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.2 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from seaborn) (3.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from seaborn) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (8.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\program files\spyder\pkgs (from pandas>=0.23->seaborn) (2021.1)
```

but when i call the library using the command

```
import seaborn as sns
```

it gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-a84c0541e888>", line 1, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

Can someone please help

Comment: Have you installed conda or anaconda? This is most likely an environment issue. Can you make sure that seaborn and Spyder are installed in a conda environment  using `conda install seaborn` and `conda install -c anaconda spyder`?

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem. Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install seaborn library using the cmd
start > run> cmd
then use the command :

```
python -m pip install seaborn
```

this should install the package, then you can use the python command line to check by
import seaborn
you can also check the installed packages using the command in the cmd:

```
pip list
```